# Write to a PDF file with fields multiple times using iTextSharp

Tags: c#, file, pdf, itext

I have a PDF document with 3 Fields `txt_FirstName`, `txt_MiddleName` and `txt_LastName` that I write into using **iTextSharp**.

I have a loop that creates the output file, writes to it, and closes the file.

The first time in the loop the file writes the first name and the middle name.

The second time in the loop the file should have the first name, middle name, and write the last name.

**Issue:** The problem is, when it goes to the loop the 2nd time around and writes the lastname the first name, and middle names disappear.

**Goal:** The main thing I want to do is write to the same PDF documents multiple times

**Download PDF template:** https://www.scribd.com/document/412586469/Testing-Doc

```
    public static string templatePath = "C:\\temp\\template.pdf";
    public static string OutputPath = "C:\\Output\\";

    private static void Fill_PDF()
    {
        string outputFile = "output.pdf";
        int counter = 1;

        for (int i = 0; i < 2; i++)
        {
            PdfStamper pdfStamper;
            PdfReader reader;

            reader = new PdfReader(File.ReadAllBytes(templatePath));
            PdfReader.unethicalreading = true;

            if (File.Exists(OutputPath + outputFile))
            {
                pdfStamper = new PdfStamper(reader, new FileStream(OutputPath + outputFile,
                                                        FileMode.Append, FileAccess.Write));
            }
            else
            {
                pdfStamper = new PdfStamper(reader, new FileStream(OutputPath + outputFile,
                                                        FileMode.Create));
            }
            AcroFields pdfFormFields = pdfStamper.AcroFields;

            if (counter == 1)
            {
                pdfFormFields.SetField("txt_FirstName", "Scooby");
                pdfFormFields.SetField("txt_MiddleName", "Dooby");
                counter++;
            }
            else if (counter == 2)
            {
                pdfFormFields.SetField("txt_LastName", "Doo");
            }
            pdfStamper.Close();
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 6):

This seems like a straightforward bug.  The first time through the loop, you load up the blank template and write the first and middle name.  The second time through the loop, you load up *the blank template again* and write *only the last name to it*, then save to the same filename, overwriting it.  If, during the second time through the loop, you want to load the file that already contains the first and middle name, you have to load up the *output file you wrote the first time around*, not the blank template again.  Or if you want to load the blank template again, inside your `if (counter == 2)` clause, you're going to have to write all 3 names, not just the last name.

I reproduced your bug, and got it working.  Here's the code to the first solution I described (minor modification of your code):

```
    public static string templatePath = "C:\\temp\\template.pdf";
    public static string OutputPath = "C:\\temp\\output\\";

    private static void Fill_PDF()
    {
        string outputFile = "output.pdf";
        int counter = 1;

        for (int i = 0; i < 2; i++)
        {
            PdfStamper pdfStamper;
            PdfReader reader = null;

            /********** here's the changed part */
            if (counter == 1)
            {
                reader = new PdfReader(File.ReadAllBytes(templatePath));
            } else if (counter == 2)
            {
                reader = new PdfReader(File.ReadAllBytes(OutputPath + outputFile));
            }
            /************ end changed part */

            PdfReader.unethicalreading = true;

            if (File.Exists(OutputPath + outputFile))
            {
                pdfStamper = new PdfStamper(reader, new FileStream(OutputPath + outputFile,
                    FileMode.Append, FileAccess.Write));
            }
            else
            {
                pdfStamper = new PdfStamper(reader, new FileStream(OutputPath + outputFile,
                    FileMode.Create));
            }
            AcroFields pdfFormFields = pdfStamper.AcroFields;

            if (counter == 1)
            {
                pdfFormFields.SetField("txt_FirstName", "Scooby");
                pdfFormFields.SetField("txt_MiddleName", "Dooby");
                counter++;
            }
            else if (counter == 2)
            {
                pdfFormFields.SetField("txt_LastName", "Doo");
            }
            pdfStamper.Close();
        }
    }
```

Comment: Your code is looks good to me and return the result as requested. One thing I dont understand from the question how come he get first and last name in Counter 2. If he is writing blank template every time from the loop, then he should loose first name too. If any one can explain it will be much better.  Thanks

Comment: Yeah, the first name gets lost as well, not sure where he stated something different.

Comment: Sorry. You are right.. Thanks for pointing out. I miss understood from reading. "Issue: The problem is, when it goes to the loop the 2nd time around and writes the lastname the first name, and middle names disappear. "

Answer (score 1):

There are two major issues with the code. @Nick in [his answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56554070/1729265) already pointed out the first: If in your second pass you want to edit a version of your document containing the changes from the first pass, you have to take the output document of the first pass as input of the second pass, not again the original template. He also presented code that fixed this issue.

The second issue is located here:

```
if (File.Exists(OutputPath + outputFile))
{
    pdfStamper = new PdfStamper(reader, new FileStream(OutputPath + outputFile,
                                            FileMode.Append, FileAccess.Write));
}
else
{
    pdfStamper = new PdfStamper(reader, new FileStream(OutputPath + outputFile,
                                            FileMode.Create));
}
```

If the output file already exists, you *append the output of your `PdfStamper` to it*. This is wrong! The output of the `PdfStamper` already contains the contents of the original PDF (from the `PdfReader`) as far as they have not being changed. Thus, your code effectively produces a concatenation of the complete output PDF of the first pass and the complete output PDF of the second pass.

PDF is a binary format for which concatenating files like that does not result in a valid PDF file. Thus, a PDF viewer loading your final result tries to repair this double PDF assuming it is a single one. The result may or may not look like you want.

To fix the second issue, simply replace the `if{...}else{...}` above by the contents of the `else` branch only:

```
pdfStamper = new PdfStamper(reader, new FileStream(OutputPath + outputFile,
                                        FileMode.Create));
```

*(`FileMode.Create` is defined as*

> Specifies that the operating system should create a new file. If the file already exists, it will be overwritten. This requires `Write` permission. `FileMode.Create` is equivalent to requesting that if the file does not exist, use `CreateNew`; otherwise, use `Truncate`. If the file already exists but is a hidden file, an `UnauthorizedAccessException` exception is thrown.

*Thus, it will also do the required if there already is a file.)*

You can recognize the problems of the code with the `Append` in it by running it a few times and watch the output file grow and grow beyond need. Furthermore, if you open that file in Adobe Reader and close again, Adobe Reader offers to save the changes; the changes are the repair work.

---

You may have heard about *incremental updates* of PDFs where changes *are* appended to the original PDF. But this is different from a mere concatenation, the revisions in the result are linked specially and the offsets are always calculated from the start of the first revision, not from the start of the current revision. Furthermore, incremental updates should only contain *changed* objects.

iText contains a `PdfStamper` constructor with 4 parameters, including a final boolean parameter `append`. Using that constructor and setting `append` to `true` makes iText creates incremental updates. But even here you don't use `FileMode.Append`...

Answer (score -1):

The problem is with using the template file again for the second iteration.

**First iteration:** works fine as expected!

**Second iteration:** you are reading the same file and writing only the last name. Finally, the output file created in the first iteration is being replaced.

**Fix:** After knowing if the output file exists in the location, choose the file source to read like below. This should fix the problem. Checked it personally and it worked!

```
if (File.Exists(OutputPath + outputFile))
{
    reader = new PdfReader(File.ReadAllBytes(OutputPath + outputFile));
    pdfStamper = new PdfStamper(reader, new FileStream(OutputPath + outputFile,
                                                            FileMode.Append, FileAccess.Write));
}
else
{
    reader = new PdfReader(File.ReadAllBytes(templatePath));
    pdfStamper = new PdfStamper(reader, new FileStream(OutputPath + outputFile,
                                                            FileMode.Create));
}
```

Comment: **A** This issue has already been described in Nick's answer. **B** Your solution has the disadvantage that it doesn't work properly if at the start of the routine there already is a (probably completely unrelated) PDF at `OutputPath + outputFile`: In that case the template may be completely ignored! Nick's solution, in contrast, always starts with the template. (Instead of the counter he probably should have used a flag or simply checked `i` but that's fine tuning). **C** That issue is only one of the two major issues of the original code.